# Could not find module 'SJSegmentedScrollView' for architecture 'armv7'; found: arm64

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

The problem shows when I try to build to real device as simulator. But, there's no problem when I build in simulator.

- XCode : 10.2.1
- Swift : 4.0
- iOS : 10.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are using Debug or Release to build? I've had a similar issue before with other modules, for example you can run the Onfido SDK on simulators on Debug but not on Release. By the looks of this error you are using the Release SDK.

Comment: Debug or Release have the same issue. Is that happened because of the iOS version?
I've been try in my simulator, and my app didn't work on iOS version below 11.0